# subquery treated as char in subquery codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, subquery, codeigniter-3

I tried to use subquery in codeigniter to get the result and use the result as the parameter in where in clause. but i got this error.

[image: ERROR THAT I GOT]

and here is my codeigniter active record query:

```
$session['hasil'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $regional = $session['hasil']->regional;

    $this->db->select('a.id_agency');
    $this->db->from('tbl_agency a');
    $this->db->join('tbl_collector_agency b', 'a.id_agency = b.id_agency', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_area_collector c', 'b.id_collector = c.id_collector', 'left');
    $this->db->join('mysystem.lapkeu.dbo.groupbranch d', 'c.group_branch_id = d.GroupBranchID', 'left');
    $this->db->where('d.regional', $regional);
    $subQuery = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->reset_query();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where_in('id_agency', $subQuery);
```

im using microsoft sql server as my database.

Comment: try to run this printed query in your phpmyadmin / adminer

Comment: im using microsoft sql server, in it runs fine when running in microsoft sql server

Comment: the active record returns the query like this SELECT * FROM "AMAS"."dbo"."tbl_agency" WHERE id_agency IN('SELECT "a"."id_agency" FROM "tbl_agency" "a" LEFT JOIN "tbl_collector_agency" "b" ON "a"."id_agency" = "b"."id_agency" LEFT JOIN "tbl_area_collector" "c" ON "b"."id_collector" = "c"."id_collector" LEFT JOIN "mysystem"."lapkeu"."dbo"."groupbranch" "d" ON "c"."group_branch_id" = "d"."GroupBranchID" WHERE "d"."regional" = ''JABODETABEK'''),